# Algorithm for creating the dual graph of a given planar graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms

Although I have some ideas on how to create a dual graph from a planar graph, I preferred to ask it here. Is there any algorithm for this purpose?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Keep in mind that the dual depends on the planar embedding. So it's not a property of the graph in abstract; geometry will be necessary.

Comment: Assume that we want to obtain the dual from a specific embedding of a graph. So what is the algorithm for this purpose?

Answer (score 4):

You may have heard of the Quad-Edge data structure for graph representation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad-edge). It has the advantage to represent the graph and its dual simultaneously, so once the graph is built, there is no need to "dualize" anymore.

I suspect that the Winged-edge structure (or even DCEL) has the same capability but this needs to be confirmed.

Comment: If a planar graph has multiple embeddings, then we may have multiple dual graphs for the planar graph. Then how this structure handles this issue?

Comment: I imagine that you need to instantiate every embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Take the set of faces as set of vertices and add an edge $f_1f_2$ whenever an edge separates these two faces.

Comment: And what is the algorithm to take the set of faces?

Comment: @m.taheri The faces should more or less be given. More precisely, we cannot compute the dual of a *planar* graph, but only the dual of a *plane* graph. As what kind of data structure is your graph and embedding into the plane given?

Comment: Imagine we have a specific embedding of a planar graph. In this case i need the algorithm for a fullerene graph. A fullerene is a 3-regular planar graph with pentagonal and hexagonal faces.